# Cannot find CmsCustomSitemapProvider applicationName

Tags: .net, iis

Hi I have uploaded my website to my live server but I get the following error.  Everything works locally, and I think I have set everything up on the server exactly the same, however I get this error.

It's a .net 2.0 application

The website works perfectly, but there is an application in the IIS setup.  When I try to access the admin (the application) this is when I get the error.

```
Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Cms.Websites.Website' could not be loaded.
```

This is the point in the web config that it is complaining about. I have no idea where my application name is referenced

```
<add name="CmsCustomSiteMapProvider" type="Cms.Websites.Website.App.CmsCustomSiteMapProvider,Cms.Websites.Website" applicationName="Website" debug="false" />
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be amazing.  Thanks

Comment: Is what in the bin?  I've got a whole load of DLL's in the bin

Comment: is the dll containing that type in there?

Comment: No, but it isn't on my local machine either, and that works.  I suspect it's a setting in IIS.  As far as I can see all settings are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after hours of settings and headaches I finally got it down to the fact that my web config file for the application was corrupt.  I've uploaded a new version and it's all working now.  Thanks.